# Creating a host application

Tags: shell-script, shell, ubuntu

How can i create an application that can transfer executables from one computer to another ? That is from one IP address to another in linux ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rsync`, `scp`, `ftp`, `sftp`, `rcp`...the list goes on.

Since you say executables, you could also check out software packaging: `apt` and `apt-get` and `dpkg`.

Look at the man pages for each of these.  `rsync` is probably all you need.

(If you haven't looked at man pages before, start with `man less` and then `man man`.)

Comment: Do i need to install something to use rsync?

Comment: @polo, no.  It's already installed.  You *do* need to learn to use the command line, though.  You might also be interested in the https://askubuntu.com site.  For example, https://askubuntu.com/q/514963/457111.